# Cant Uninstall apk because it doesn't show up

Tags: java, android, certificate, apk, uninstallation

He there,

My problem is that I have a signed apk that I installed after making it in eclipse. It has no errors when I test it in the emulator but when I transfer it to my real device (rooted kindle fire with ICS) I can't find the app. It doesn't show up in the launcher or in  Settings>Apps in any category.

I want to install a new unsigned version but I can't because I can't uninstall the first one and it gives me a certificate error.

Using Eclipse Juno on Windows 7 building as android version 2.1 and running on 4.0.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try 'adb uninstall "package name"' from the command line?

Package name should be something like: com.mycompany.myapp

Comment: i dont have a pc mini usb connector. If so though, would i do "adb uninstall com.erik.decker"?

Comment: You can run adb trough wifi in android 4

Answer (score 0):

there are several command line interface apps available in market ... install them and then try "adb uninstall "package name" " ... try apps like **terminal emulator**

Comment: adb on terminal emulator says "waiting for device" and never goes past that

Answer (score 0):

I would use this app, have used it numerous times....

[Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImphY2twYWwuYW5kcm9pZHRlcm0iXQ..)